# TFS 2018 - Error during download: System.UriFormatException: Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determined

Tags: tfs, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, tfs-2018

I have created a release definition in Team Foundation Server 2018 based on a build definition.
When the release is started for the respective build environment I get the following error message:

`Error during download: System.UriFormatException: Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determined.`

This error occurs during the release process "Download artifacts".

Question:

- Where can I find this URI in Team Foundation Server 2018 which has an incorrect format?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have found the error.

In my build definition predefined variables are used.
For example, in this `$(BuildTargetPath)\App\YourFavoriteProgram\` specification, `$(BuildTargetPath)` is a variable defined in the variable group.

However, I had forgotten to include the variable group in the build definition under "Variables" > "Variable Groups".